# ViewState asking for instance of object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to a viewdate in code as can be seen below and i am getting the error message below, any ideas why this would be happening.

Code being used

```
var state = ViewState["GridViewIndex"].ToSting()
```

Error Message

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: Where is this code being used?  At what point in the page life-cycle?  And had a value actually be set *into* ViewState["GridViewIndex"]?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var state = Convert.ToString(ViewState["GridViewIndex"]);
```

instead of `ToString()`

This won't crash when `ViewState["GridViewIndex"]` is null and just return null or string.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting that error is because ViewState["GridViewIndex"] is not an instance of an object.

ViewState is like a dicionary, but for a given key you might get a null reference, if no object is instantiated. Please change your code to check for null references because convert it to string.

Something like

```
string state = string.Empty;
if(ViewState["GridViewIndex"] != null)
{
   state = ViewState["GridViewIndex"].ToString();
}
```

or might also use Convert.ToString instead of ToString as RononDex told us, but in general we need to check for null references.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewState["GridViewIndex"] = 'get the value
var state = string.empty;
if(ViewState["GridViewIndex"] != null)
{
   state = ViewState["GridViewIndex"].ToString();
}
```

Since you haven't assigned any values to the **ViewState["GridViewIndex"]** it throws an error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
so first assign a value then pass it to the variable state.

Hope this helps

Happy Coding